# Mvvmcross iOS Push Notification Setup

Tags: apple-push-notifications, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am looking at setting my app up with push notifications. Is there currently a mvvmcross demo that uses push notifications across all platforms? I saw some third party libraries such as pushsharp that handles most but was wondering if anyone has a preferred preference to set it up for cross platform development.

I'm still a relative beginner in mobile dev so I've read the basics of push setup in the xamarin docs.

Any sample code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if you have checked **Azure Notification Hub**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj927170.aspx